Support for plugins in messengers like WhatsApp: thoughts about how chatters would respond to base thoughts, modeled interactions, and sending thought
Let me talk first about an analogous development. In the field of text editing, first, there were a variety of text editors like Notepad, Vim, and Emacs, on PCs (personal computers). Then, when people wanted to do more with text, things like Word, IDEs for code like Eclipse, Visual Studio, and IntelliJIDEA came about.
Today, I hold the same vision for messengers, which, are indeed, very simple... but could be made more complex, via plugins.
For instance, take a messenger like WhatsApp.
What if, via a plugin, you could include a software layer above the messenger application, that allowed you, for instance, to make custom UI, elements, accessible... or add another application window element above the layer, that, allowed you to do something (such as the following):
Suppose you could code a number of base thoughts, which could be all accessible though a menu that summarized the base thoughts (like in chatgpt chats are summarized with an AI generated heading).
So, we have
"Base thoughts"
For each base thought, we have a chat-like window where we can jot down

predicted responses, for each person we think about sending the base thought. This predicted response, has a date, corresponding to when we think the response will be generated. Thus, we can include more than one timestamped predictions.

We can even include a given predicted chat flowchart (with things I say, and things the other person says, and what we say in each case).


This is all private. The other party does not see it. It remains, on the server, for our account.

actual response: via the plugin, we can choose to send the base thought to a chatter (i.e. a real contact), in which case the plugin window records base thought sent, and the chat displays the base thought in the chat

in the plugin window, we may also have sections where we jot down notes (which could be stuff such as, the person said this in the chat, and did it (on time), or didn't do it.


This, would make, chat programs more versatile
Who is willing to implement this idea?
Thank you for your implementations.
Thank you for your support.
Thanks.
